# Is it possible to make class inside other class' body in other file than declaration in C#?

Tags: c#

```
namespace Program 
{
    class Test 
    {
        public Test() { }

        public class InsideClass 
        {
              public InsideClass() { }

              public void Call() { }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write `Program::Test::InsideClass:: Call`'s body in other files than the same Test.

Like in c++ there is `.h` file where you declare function and `.cpp` where is the function's body.

Comment: No, the function declaration and body go together in C#.

Comment: @Amy no, not always, even when talking about methods ("function declaration") - see "partial methods", "partial classes", etc

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I'm familiar with `partial class`, I don't think that applies here, as the method declaration is still with the body.  I'm not familiar with partial methods though.

Comment: For me as a C# developer(not C++) i wonder why you think that you need it. This _smells_ like an XY problem, your code got messy and you want to refactor it with the wrong tool.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? C++ H files serve a lot of purposes, but mostly because of the needs of the C++ compile/link cycle. .NET‐land is very different (with fully compiled and consumable metadata available in assemblies. You can get some of what I think you are talking about by pairing interfaces with classes. You can get some from partial classes & partial methods. But they are both designed to answer different questions than the one I think you are asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C#, unlike C++, does not separate the declaration from the implementation. There is nothing comparable to `.h` files. The main reason is that the metadata in the .NET DLL files contains the information that would be in the header files in C++. The C++ `#include` is replaced by referencing the DLLs in the C# project. Also, you can selectively import namespaces with the `using` statement. But namespaces have no physical effect. They are just a way to organize code and to avoid naming conflicts.

But you can create partial classes in C#. This allows you to move private helper methods to another file. In `Test.cs` you write

```
public partial class Test
{
    public Test() { }

    public partial class InsideClass
    {
        public InsideClass() { }
        public void PublicMethod() => PrivateHelper();
    }
}
```

In `Test.Implementation.cs` you write

```
public partial class Test
{
    public partial class InsideClass
    {
        private void PrivateHelper() { }
    }
}
```

The WinForms designer uses partial classes to separate designer generated code (`myForm.designer.cs`) from your behind code (`myForm.cs`).

You can do this even with nested classes. Note that nested classes can be partial, even when the surrounding class is not. (But then they can't be in different files obviously.)

In Visual Studio, you can also use the Class View to display the logical structure of code instead of the physical structure as the Solution Explorer does. The Object Browser is another helpful view.

See also:

- [Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)
- [Classes / Partial types (C# language specification)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#partial-types)

Comment: Well, he wanted not the whole class in the other file but only `Call`s body

Comment: @Tim that is *sort of* possible via partial methods, but... Nobody ever does, and it makes life hard - they have very limited features, which means you end up having to expose them in arcane ways

Comment: @MarcGravell: yes i saw your comment and read about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/partial-method
I have never used and missed it though

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you make partial classes which might accomplish what you seek.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

**First file:**

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}
```

**Second file:**

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how does the "accepted answer"?  It is basically the exact same thing just posted seconds before.  Please explain.